# Is it possible to define dynamic projections in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a query joining many tables. I'd like to be able to parametrize what fields should be retrieved (sometimes complex SQL Postgis functions). Let's say the initial query is built like this:

```
def buildQuery() = for {
  c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
  s <- c.supplier
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```

Now I want one of the yielded values to be dependent on my parameter, so the example would become:

```
val param = true
def buildQuery() = for {
  c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0
  s <- c.supplier
} yield (c.name, if (param) s.name else null)
```

Such code won't work, Slick internals throw a NullPointerException.
Is there any reasonable way to dynamically build the yield part based on input parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you could use slick's "case dsl": https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Case.scala

Comment: Looks like we can't really achieve the 'null' element with this DSL. Also, it works for `Column[]` but not for tables, like in this case: `yield (c.name, s)` with condition for `s`.

Comment: you could realize "null" using '... else LiteralNode("null")'

Comment: You're right, in 2.1. this is restricted to using a type of `Column` as of `... def Then(res: Column[T])... ` (see: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1/src/main/scala/scala/s/lifted/Case.scala). Slick master on the other side restricts the type to `Rep` (see: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/Case.scala) which is a base type of `Column` and (!) `Table`. It should be possible to use a condition on `s` with the change applied in slick master.

Comment: I tried to apply this in the Slick Activator (with dependency updated to 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT), but this code:
`val cond: Boolean = true;
    val joinQuery = for {
      c <- coffees if c.price > 9.0;
      s <- c.supplier
    } yield (c.name, Case If cond Then s.name Else LiteralNode("null"))` gives quite a few compilation errors.

Comment: Try something like `if (param) s.name.? else null.?` but using Slick's Case DSL